# suppress bluebird warnings for specific promise

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I'm using bluebird promises mixed with 3rd party library. Recently I encountered warnings like:

> Warning: a promise was created in a handler but was not returned from it, see http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/warning-explanations.html#warning-a-promise-was-created-in-a-handler-but-was-not-returned-from-it

I tracked down the issue to this scenario:

- My code calls external library
- External library executes some computations and in some situations it might call listeners that I registered in it
- My listener creates a promise that is returned in the end to the library

Now the problem: external library doesn't return the promise returned by my listener to my original code. Therefore bluebird shows a warning.

I'm not able to modify external library.

I would like to disable the warnings for promise created in my listener. Is it possible?

I'm aware of this: http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.config.html. However it's a global config and will disable warnings for all of my promises.

Comment: a) Don't return promises to the library if that library isn't using them. b) In your original code, `return null` from the `then` callback to signify that you don't want to wait for any created promises. For concrete help, please post your code and link the library you are using.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to solve it using your hints. I know that with code it would be easier, but I had problems with limiting the code to reasonable size...